# Codeigniter and i18n for ajax url

Tags: codeigniter, internationalization

I'm using i18n for multi language site in codeginiter . But How i can get baseURL with language ID ('en', 'fr', ...) to use it for Ajax calls in js files.

Comment: I tried to put var baseURL = <?php echo base_url($this->uri->segment(1)); ?> in the header section. but i think there is something better, i don't know if i can't adding as default the lang id if nothing specified.

Comment: For example `www.domain.com/url/for/ajax` will be redirect to `www.domain.com/en/url/for/ajax`

Comment: possible solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091171/add-uri-segment-for-language-in-codeigniter/14091238#14091238)

Comment: I have a question please, How i can make lang as subdomain like : `www.en.example.com`

Comment: subdomains are separate folders with their own cgi. you can create a subdomain in your website name it as en. call it on specified link. but make sure you have the permission for creating subdomain in from your host.

Comment: So i think they are two separated apps ?

Comment: If you want them to be into two separate subdomains

Comment: No, I like to be the same app but how i can do this.

Comment: Have you seen the possible solution I mentioned?